# Автоматическое получение токена авторизации ВКонтакте на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я использую библиотеку:

https://github.com/sgaynetdinov/py-vkontakte

```
import vk

api = vk.Api('YOUR_TOKEN')
```

Где для авторизации используется токен, в ручную его можно получить по ссылке:

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=XXX&response_type=token

Он возвращается в адресной строке:

https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=YYY&expires_in=86400&user_id=XXX

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ автоматического получения токена на Python

Answer (score 1):

Решил так

```
from credentials import vk
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'/chromedriver'
)

driver.get("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=XXX&response_type=token")

# Для удобства сохраняем XPath формы авторизации
username = '//*[@id="login_submit"]/div/div/input[6]'
password = '//*[@id="login_submit"]/div/div/input[7]'
login = '//*[@id="install_allow"]'

# Заполняем форму авторизации
driver.find_element_by_xpath(username).send_keys(vk['login'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password).send_keys(vk['password'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login).click()

print(driver.current_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать selenium, для такого, который в headless режиме будет вместо тебя заходить на определенную ссылку и брать токен!

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/