# Ошибка cannot import name 'vk' from 'credentials' как исправить?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, selenium, веб-сайт

Вот код который у меня, взято с Stakoverflow и почему-то не работает, помогите как исправить ?

```
from credentials import vk
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'/chromedriver'
)

driver.get("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=496658805&response_type=token")

# Для удобства сохраняем XPath формы авторизации
username = '//*[@id="login_submit"]/div/div/input[6]'
password = '//*[@id="login_submit"]/div/div/input[7]'
login = '//*[@id="install_allow"]'

# Заполняем форму авторизации
driver.find_element_by_xpath(username).send_keys(vk['login'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath(password).send_keys(vk['password'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login).click()

print(driver.current_url)
```

Ошибка :

```
C:\Users\Матвей\Desktop\APP>python prs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from credentials import vk
ImportError: cannot import name 'vk' from 'credentials' 
(C:\Users\Матвей\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\credentials\__init__.py)
```

Comment: В Вашем `credentials` нет модуля `vk`. Возможно, что в исходном тексте была другая библиотека с тем же названием или форк.

Comment: @AndyPavlov Понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего в данном случае так подключается локальный файл `credentials.py`, в котором у автора кода описан класс `vk` с полями `login` и `password`, в которых прописаны логин и пароль для входа.

Т.е. это не какая-то стандартная библиотека, а локальный файл настроек.

Comment: ну и как мне это исправить, я пробовал заменить login и password в строках 16 17 и это не помогло, пробовал удалить строку from credentials import vk не помогло а в Классах я не сильно понимаю так что прошу совета что делать

Comment: Напишите коммент автору поста, где вы скопировали код.  Может он Вам объяснит, что у него там сидит

Comment: к моему сожелению я не могу коментировать его ответ из-за нехватки репутации (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161884/Автоматическое-получение-токена-авторизации-ВКонтакте-на-python) + последняя его активность 13 мая